# Performance Issue: AWS Medium Linux Instance V/S Hetzner Dedicated Instance

Tags: centos, performance, mysql

I am testing an AWS Medium Instance with CentOS (AWS AMI) and comparing it with Hetzner's EX40-SSD (http://www.hetzner.de/hosting/produkte_rootserver/ex40ssd). Software setup on both is comparable( Same OS, Same version of MySQL 5.6.14). CPU Speed of AWS was 2Ghz and CPU Speed of Hetzner was 3.4GHZ. mysql my.cnf was exactly same for both the servers. Have a large abc.sql file which has dump from another server (2GB Size) copied locally onto both the above servers.  I ran the following command on both the machines #

```
date > StartTime ; mysql -pxyz < abc.sql ; date >> StartTime &
```

Strangely, the AWS Small instance completed the task in 12 mins where as the Hetzner instance took more than 40 mins to complete the task.

There are no other servers/apps running on Hetzner machine (Clean machine with only MySQL). AWS Machine has other software running like SugarCRM, Piwik, Nginx, but not loaded.

What could be the reason why the AWS outperformed the Hetzner ? Logically, Hetzner should be faster as it has SSD (Faster IO), faster CPU (3.4Ghz) and operating as Dedicated Machine and not a VM instance. How to debug and trace the root cause for such strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
date > StartTime; mysql …; date >> StartTime
```

you can simple use

```
time mysql …
```

which will give you an output like this once the command has finished:

```
0.02s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 8.828 total
```

Regarding your performance issues:

- Have you looked at `htop` to identify potential high CPU/memory usage of specific processes.
- What are the [system load values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29) during/right after the operation?

If `htop` doesn't reveal much, you could use more advanced utilities to find bottlenecks of your system like:

- [dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/)
- [perf](http://perf.wiki.kernel.org/)
- latencytop
- [sysprof](http://sysprof.com/)
- [ktap](https://github.com/ktap/ktap)

Comment: htop has not shown any load on the system. Once in a while the CPU goes above 25% mainly consumed by mysqld task. Lot of free memory to consume. Swam is not used. Average CPU usage is at 3-4%.

Comment: htop screen shot while the mysql upload in progress. https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/g2gmarketingdocs/htop.png

Comment: time mysql.. resulted in the following: 
real    22m2.995s
user    0m11.044s
sys     0m0.508s  
For this run I had set optimization for innodb, SSD IO and hence it is showing 22minutes. Without these optimizations it shows 40 min.

Comment: Since you're only seeing 11.5 seconds of CPU time being used over 22 minutes of real time, looks like the difference is in I/O speed. Which is surprising if you're using EBS storage since EBS is not particularly fast, but I think that even the instance store storage is backed by spinning hard drives so I'd expect your SSD's to be much faster.

Comment: Johnny, that is exactly my concern. SSD's offer very high IO Rates in comparison to any HDD but the results show otherwise. Could this be because of very slow Erase/Write operations of SSD? Has anyone else observed this? Would the current SSD configuration server perform better for live data in production use?

Comment: A tool I forgot to add to my list, but which could you give easily insight in this situation: [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).